# Querying RDB$TRANSACTIONS Table in Firebird (2.1)

Tags: transactions, metadata, firebird

How do I use the metadata related to transactions in firebird (using version 2.1) ?

So for example:

1) Open a isql session, change some table, hold transaction open.

2) Open another isql session, execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM RDB$TRANSACTIONS;
```

returns no rows. Is there something special I need to enable to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

A table RDB$TRANSACTIONS is used only for distributed transactions (i.e transactions which run against more than one database). For monitoring regular transactions use table MON$TRANSACTIONS instead.

```
MON$TRANSACTIONS (started transactions)
  - MON$TRANSACTION_ID (transaction ID)
  - MON$ATTACHMENT_ID (attachment ID)
  - MON$STATE (transaction state)
       0: idle
       1: active
  - MON$TIMESTAMP (transaction start date/time)
  - MON$TOP_TRANSACTION (top transaction)
  - MON$OLDEST_TRANSACTION (local OIT number)
  - MON$OLDEST_ACTIVE (local OAT number)
  - MON$ISOLATION_MODE (isolation mode)
       0: consistency
       1: concurrency
       2: read committed record version
       3: read committed no record version
  - MON$LOCK_TIMEOUT (lock timeout)
      -1: infinite wait
       0: no wait
       N: timeout N
  - MON$READ_ONLY (read-only flag)
  - MON$AUTO_COMMIT (auto-commit flag)
  - MON$AUTO_UNDO (auto-undo flag)
  - MON$STAT_ID (statistics ID)
```

Comment: SQL> select * from MON$TRANSACTIONS;
    Statement failed, SQLCODE = -204
    Dynamic SQL Error
    -SQL error code = -204
    -Table unknown
    -MON$TRANSACTIONS
    -At line 1, column 15
    SQL> show version;
    ISQL Version: WI-V2.1.1.17910 Firebird 2.1
    Server version:
    Firebird/x86/Windows NT (access method), version "WI-V2.1.1.17910 Firebird 2.1

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, SO won't let me indent it for some reason. It says that I don't have the MON$TRANSACTIONS table.

Comment: What ODS version of your database? Did you backup/restore it? Seems like older database being accessed via new server.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what is an ODS version?

Comment: On Disk Structure. Version of internal structure of database file. New versions of Firebird introduce new ODS but can work with older versions. Monitoring tables MON$ where introduced only in recent ODS.